# Need sibling divs to overlap side-by-side at larger breakpoint and flex column at smaller breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, breakpoints

So I have an image-container div and a text-container div; above `768px` width they should be side by side, slightly overlapping (this part works). But when the viewer is under `768px`, they should flex column, with the image first and the text below. I've done this in another block with similar cards that don't overlap, but I'm having trouble with the flex-direction: column working on this one. They just end up on top (z-index) of each other. Here's my code:

```html
    <div class="promo-container"> <!-- flex for large, flex column for small -->
        <div class="promo_image-container_img-right promo_image-container rounded-3xl p-5 text-cfcu-supplementary-gray-10 bg-cfcu-supplementary-gray-75">
            <img src="{{$image['url']}}" class="p-5 max-w-80 max-h-52" />
        </div>
        <div class="promo_text-container_img-right promo_text-container rounded-3xl p-5">
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold">{{$title}}</div>
            <div class="my-2">{{$description}}</div>
            <a href="{{$button_url}}"><button id="promotion-cta-button" class="bg-black text-white font-bold p-2 rounded-full">{{$button_text}}</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    .promo-container {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 28rem;
    }

    .promo_text-container_img-left {
        background: white;
        width: 60%;
        z-index: 100;
        margin-left: -35px;
        height: 80%;
        position: relative;   
    }

    .promo_image-container_img-left {
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .promo_text-container_img-right {
        background: white;
        width: 53%;
        z-index: 100;
        margin-right: -15px;
        height: 80%;
        position: absolute;   
        left: 0;
    }

    .promo_image-container_img-right {
        width: 53%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
        .promo-container {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .promo_image-container, .promo_text-container {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .promo_text-container {
            position: relative;
        }
    }
```

There's also the option on the larger breakpoint to have the image on the left or the image on the right, hence the two sets of `.promo_text-container_img-{{direction}}` classes.

Comment: The flex column works when the image is on the left, so it's something I did with the img-right classes... still looking

Comment: Don't add new information in comments, please. Put it in your question. Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that since I added `position: absolute;` to `.promo_image-container_img-right` to reverse the order of the divs, I had to restore `relative` for `flex-direction: column;` to work at the small breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .promo_image-container_img-right {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```